# Snap applications through a remote X11 session

Tags: x11-forwarding, snapcraft, ubuntu-20.04

I noticed that on Ubuntu 20.04, a lot of software is made available through [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) and it does not even appear in the distribution's "sources".

This is all good, but when you try to run an application that has graphic output and have it connect via remote X11 to your machine, snap seems to be `Unable to open X display`. Which is strange, because `gnumeric` (for example) runs as a remote X11 application just fine.

I suspect that this is a configuration problem. Any ideas on how to run a remote X11 application via snap appropriately?

Answer (score 3):

Try running this on the remote host before launching the snap application:

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

Comment: This worked for me at least. But why do snap apps need XAUTHORITY, when e.g. `gnumeric` or `xclock` don't?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Ah, now I (partly) understand. Entschuldigung ;-) I have fixed my typo. Only thing that remains is: Who/what is Queen? Some automated system?

Comment: They have an avatar, you can look them up among the users. https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen Automatic yes, but hardly (not at all as far as I know) ever flagging automatically. But if Queen buzzes because of anything you type, you can be sure that somebody is going to come nosing around.